# How to escape record insert if condition is not met

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a 3rd party API which I am to insert into the DB using ASP.NET Core-6 Web API.

API:

```
"https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/api/BranchDetail"
```

In appsettings.json I have:

```
"Endpoints": {
  "branchUrl": "https://api.thirdpartycompany.com:2233/api/BranchDetail"
}
```

API:

```
{
    "Branches": [
        {
            "BranchName": "Accra",
            "BranchNumber": 1,
            "BranchType": "Human Resource Agency",
        },
        {
            "BranchName": "Kumasi",
            "BranchNumber": 2,
            "BranchType": "Production"
        },
        ...
}
```

The core is as shown below:

Entity:

```
public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string BranchType { get; set; }
    public int BranchNumber { get; set; }
}
```

DTO:

```
public class BranchCreateUpdateDto
{
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string BranchType { get; set; }
    public int BranchNumber { get; set; }
}

public class BranchResponse
{
    public List<BranchCreateUpdateDto> Branches
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

BaseResponse:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Service:

Interface:

```
Task<BaseResponse> CreateBranchAsync();
```

Implementation:

```
public class AdminBranchService : IAdminBranchService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly HttpClient _myClient;
    public AdminBranchService(
        ApplicationDbContext dbContext,
        IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
        ILogger logger,
        IMapper mapper,
        IConfiguration config,
        HttpClient myClient
        )
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _mapper = mapper;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _logger = logger;
        _config = config;
        _myClient = myClient;
    }
    public async Task<BaseResponse> CreateBranchAsync()
    {
        var branchResponse = new BaseResponse();
        var branches = new List<Branch>();
        try
        {
            string branchUrl = _config.GetSection("Endpoints").GetValue<string>("branchUrl");
            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            _myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = _myClient.GetAsync(branchUrl).Result;

            var stringResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            BranchResponse list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BranchResponse>(stringResult);


        // filter branches based on BranchType
        var filteredBranches = list.Branches
            .Where(x => x.BranchType.StartsWith("Human Resource")
                || x.BranchType.StartsWith("Production"));

            foreach (var singleBranch in filteredBranches)
            {
                Branch res = new Branch();
                if (_dbContext.Branches.Any(x => x.BranchName == singleBranch.BranchName))
                {
                    res.BranchNumber = singleBranch.BranchNumber;
                    _unitOfWork.Branches.Update(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    //set all fields here
                    res.BranchName = singleBranch.BranchName;
                    res.BranchNumber = singleBranch.BranchNumber;
                    await _unitOfWork.Branches.InsertAsync(res);
                }
                await _unitOfWork.Save();
            }              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("An Error occured " + ex.ToString());
        }
        return branchResponse;
    }
}
```

As stated earlier, I am to insert new records from the third party API and update existing record into the DB.

However, for some of the records, I got this error in the **InsertAsync(res)**

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

How do I tell the application through the code to insert the next record whenever this occurs?

Comment: can you add the code of the `InsertAsync` method? Is the exception happening inside the `InsertAsync` method or maybe `_unitOfWork.Branches` is `null`?

Comment: @theemee - Kindly write a sample of the code

Comment: `"for some of the records"` what kind of records? Does your api returns null data? Did are you checking null conditionals? Does your database allow null data? Please share these information for more troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way: Just change the place of the try..catch block:

```
foreach (var singleBranch in filteredBranches)
            {
                Branch res = new Branch();
            try
            {
                if (_dbContext.Branches.Any(x => x.BranchName == singleBranch.BranchName))
                {
                    res.BranchNumber = singleBranch.BranchNumber;
                    _unitOfWork.Branches.Update(res);
                }
                else
                {
                    //set all fields here
                    res.BranchName = singleBranch.BranchName;
                    res.BranchNumber = singleBranch.BranchNumber;
                    await _unitOfWork.Branches.InsertAsync(res);
                }
                await _unitOfWork.Save();
             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            _logger.Error("An Error occured " + ex.ToString());
            }
         }
```

Comment: I did that but not solving the problem